# Create React App: src and public folders are not creating on installation

Tags: reactjs, hadoop-yarn, antd, npx

I am trying to create a React project when using `npx` or using `yarn` always freezes,

this is the `CMD` part when using the `npx`:

```
D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects>npx create-react-app my_app_test --use-npm
npx: installed 98 in 50.461s

Creating a new React app in D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects\my_app_test.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects\my_app_test\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects\my_app_test\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects\my_app_test\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react@16.13.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
added 1624 packages from 750 contributors and audited 1628 packages in 1030.934s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

and freezes when using `yarn` command aswell as the below cmd:

```
D:\React_Redux_Course>yarn create react-app setup-antd-first
yarn create v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-react-app@3.4.1" with binaries:
      - create-react-app

Creating a new React app in D:\React_Redux_Course\setup-antd-first.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 14 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
└─ react@16.13.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.10.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.10.1
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.9.0
├─ babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
├─ react-dev-utils@10.2.1
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.7
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
├─ react@16.13.1
└─ scheduler@0.19.1
Done in 212.18s.
```

I don't know where's the problem exactly may be there's still missing package need to install or something?

and for both I didn't find the `src` folder and always stuck or freeze as I explained...

Please give me some recommendation...

## Edited:

this is a screen shot for meaning freeze:

[image: Freeze]

and this is the project folder:

[image]

Comment: what means `freezes`? it looks like everything installed successful

Comment: It might possible that your folder does not have right permission... otherwise according to your code snippet it looks good and your react application is also created successfully.  do check once.

Comment: @demkovych could you check edit I have just add n image may be explain what I mean with freeze

Comment: try to run `yarn install --frozen-lockfile --network-concurrency 1`

Comment: @aananddham may be I should open the cmd as an admin?

Comment: @demkovych I tried and i think it's working fine as this is the info message `info No lockfile found.`

Comment: It might be helpful to you: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4147

Comment: or just check this thread: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should remove your old version of `create-react-app` cli

Now do the following thing you can able to create your application.

1. `npm rm -g create-react-app`
2. `npm install -g create-react-app`
3. `npx create-react-app my-app`

Note: 
When using correct create-react-app version, you will see an additional package `cra-template`

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
```

While previous versions show something like this:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
```

Comment: wow you saved my time bro thanks alot it solved finally

Comment: Cheers mate...!!!